# Unable to complete set up of ADT in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu, adt

I am using Ubuntu 11.10. I have extracted the "android-sdk_r20.0.3-linux.tgz" in the "Downloads" directory. While trying to set the location of SDK during installing ADT in Eclipse, I can see the "android-sdk_r20.0.3-linux.tgz" file but its greyed out. I am therefore unable to select it to complete setting up ADT.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

*.tgz is an archive. Extract the files from it and then point Eclipse to the folder.